# Interface syntax in Java

Tags: java, interface

The code below compiles:

```
interface A {
    void foo();
}

interface B extends A {
    void bar();
}

class FooBar implements A, B {
    ...
}
```

It would be cleaner to just say `class FooBar implements B`. Is there any reason other than clarity to do it that way? Or might I run into some trouble down the road if I use the pattern on display in the sample code.

Comment: No, there's no reason to do that. Both examples are equivalent.

Comment: From a readability point of view, it's easy to ascertain the implementation hierarchy, but you don't always want to do it as it clutters the code. If you generate JavaDocs from your code, you will be able to see the inheritance hierarchy anyway, personally I'd just use `B` and not worry about `A` unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise

Comment: There was a Javadoc bug 20 years ago whereby information from inherited information wasn't printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the compiler it doesn't make a difference.

For human readers it can make the code more understandable in some cases. When your interface names are `Animal` and `Mammal`, declaring both is redundant since everyone knows that mammals are animals. But if the interfaces are not so closely related, such as `DataTransferObject` and `Serializable`, it can be useful to explicitly list both.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly declaring that `FooBar` implements `A` is completely redundant, and nay modern IDE can be configured to warn about this redundancy.

If it's not obvious from the names that `B` extends `A`, declaring `FooBar` in such a way may make it a tad easier to understand, but more often than not that just means you need to rethink the relationship between `B` and `A`.